# How can I view and manage appointments?

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I need to fetch all appointment created in Exchange server to my web application using C#.

I also need to create new appointments in Exchange server using C#.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a similar question I answered recently. It requires the use of EWS Managed API. Check out this post and see if it helps:

[What would be the simplest way to display an Exhange/Outlook meeting room's calendar on a webpage using Exchange Web Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691242/what-would-be-the-simplest-way-to-display-an-exhange-outlook-meeting-rooms-cale)

Also, to create new appointments in Exchange, check out this article on MSDN:

[How to: Create appointments and meetings by using EWS in Exchange 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn495611(v=exchg.150).aspx)