# Getting location from EmailMessage in exchange

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchange-transport-agents

I can read an `EmailMessage`. Now I need to get the location property using C#.

[image]

I can access the properties like `Subject`, `From`, `To` and etc but did not find any property like `Location`

Basically I am developing a custom transport agent for Exchange. In the `OnEndOfData` handler, I need Location.

```
private void MazeMapAgent_OnEndOfData(ReceiveMessageEventSource source, EndOfDataEventArgs e)
        {
            EmailMessage emailMessage = e.MailItem.Message;
        }
```

## Update

`EmailMessage` is a type of `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.Email.EmailMessage` not `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage`

Comment: Perhaps you need this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691242/what-would-be-the-simplest-way-to-display-an-exhange-outlook-meeting-rooms-cale

Comment: Isn't this an Appointment and not EmailMessage? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment_members(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I got this as  `EmailMessage` and can't extract the location from it

Comment: Try this sample code https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn641961(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: See my update. I dont have access in `ExchangeService`

Comment: But you are using Exchange Managed Api right?

Comment: Yes I am using ... What to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EmailMessage is a type of Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.Email.EmailMessage not Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage

Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage is an EWS Class and you don't use EWS in a Transport Agent.

You wont get that property out of the EmailMessage class i would suggest

If you have a TNEFStream https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa579434(v=exchg.140).aspx then you need to parse the TNEF properties on the message using the TNEFReader and you should then be able to get that Mapi property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842419.aspx

You should also be able to use the iCal Reader https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa579407(v=exchg.140).aspx theres a sample for that http://blogs.technet.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=jasoning&y=2011&m=08&d=17&WeblogPostName=icalendar-property-rewrite

Comment: Huge thanks! You got my actual problem. Solved using `CalendarReader`

Comment: Can you please help with this question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38367946/1294606