# Getting null in e.MailItem.Message.CalendarPart in exchange transport agent

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchange-transport-agents

I am developing a custom transport agent for Exchange 2013. I am getting `null` in `e.MailItem.Message.CalendarPart` though I am sending a meeting request.

```
   if (e.MailItem.Message.CalendarPart != null)
        {
            LocationProcessorStrategy.AddLocationInBody(e.MailItem.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            e.MailItem.Message.Subject += " [There is no calendar part - added by agent.]";
        }
```

`e.MailItem.Message.MapiMessageClass` is giving me the value `"IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request"` but `CalendarPart` is null.

Answer (score 0):

That generally means that at the Messaging stage you trying to intercept the message there is no ICal Body part to parse. iCal is usually create post categorisation depending on the recipient type https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232174(v=exchg.150).aspx . So either push your Agent to run after categorisation has occurred or use the TNEFReader/TNEFWriter to parse the TNEFStream for the message. Note you may need two solution if you want process bother internal and external Calendar Invites because of the formats used.

Comment: How can I run my agent after categorization?

Comment: Also can you please give a sample code link of reading tnef properties?

Comment: Use OnCategorizedMessage https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125012(v=exchg.150).aspx for the TNEF stream see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mstehle/2009/01/13/howto-sample-transport-agent-add-headers-categories-mapi-props-even-uses-a-fork/ and http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/reading-custom-mapi-properties-in.html

Comment: can not find any event like `OnCategorizedMessage` under `SmtpReceiveAgent`

Comment: Got it under `RoutingAgent`. but no my question is: Can I change the email body from `RoutingAgent`?

Comment: Calendar Part is also null under `OnCategorizedMessage`

Comment: If its an Internal messages from mailbox to mailbox within the same org then there is no point in the categorizer doing a conversion to iCal so I suspect all you will ever have in a TNEFStream so you will need to access the properties in that Stream. The body can be Routing agent see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204066(v=exchg.140).aspx